# Conversion of List to ObservableCollection Freezing the UI in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, observablecollection

```
ObservableCollection<Transaction> transactions;

public ObservableCollection<Transaction> Transactions
{
        get { return transactions; }
        set
        {
                transactions = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("transactions");
        }
}
    
private Property selectedProperty;

public Property SelectedProperty
{
        get { return selectedProperty; }
        set
        {
                selectedProperty = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedProperty");
                Task.Run(async () => await GetTransactions());
        }
}

private async Task GetTransactions()
{
        try
        {
                IsProgressing = true;
                if (SelectedProperty == null)
                {
                        Transactions = null;
                        return;
                }

                var tranList = new List<Transaction>();
                decimal balance = 0;
                foreach (var tran in await context.Transactions
                    .Where(t => t.PropertyId == SelectedProperty.Id)
                    .OrderBy(t => t.Date).ToListAsync())
                {
                        if (!tran.IsMisc)
                        {
                                balance = balance - tran.AmountPaid + tran.AmountDue;
                        }
                        if (tran.IsRentStart)
                        {
                                balance = 0;
                        }
                        tran.Balance = balance;
                        tranList.Add(tran);
                }

                Transactions = new ObservableCollection<Transaction>(
                    tranList.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date));
                OutstandingAmount = Transactions.Select(t => t.Balance)
                    .FirstOrDefault() + SelectedProperty.OutstandingAmount;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        }
        finally
        {
                IsProgressing = false;
        }
}
```

On calling the `GetTransactions()` on `SelectedProperty` change of the dropdown, the UI freezes until the records are shown in the `DataGrid`.

I think conversion of `List<Transaction>` to `ObservableCollection<Transaction>` is the cause. I have tried many methods like `Task.Run()`, using `Dispather.BeginInvoke` but nothing is working.
Getting values from the database `Context.Transaction.Where()....ToListAsync()) does not freeze the UI, I have checked that. On removing the 'List' to 'ObservableCollection' conversion the UI is not freezing.

Comment: It's unclear why you think you need an ObservableCollection at all. You don't seem to be adding or removing elements to/from the Transactions collection anywhere in your code.

Comment: Even if I use List<Transaction> the same thing happens

Comment: Have you checked that everything is running on the main thread? How many items do you have in the collection?

Comment: 132 Entries only

Comment: IMO the UI is frozen because the constructor of the List/OC requires that the await iterator is complete, because it needs to enumerate all of its items and write it in the List/OC. Thus the LINQ query is the heavy task, but it is hidden behinds its caller which is forced on the UI thread.

Comment: I got the issue resolved. The C# code was not the reason for UI freeze but the rendering of records on thr DataGrid. I set EnableRowVirtualization="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True". Actually DataGrid freezes the UI on large data. So enabling virtualization resolves the issue